# Image element not placed properly inside div

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I try to place an img into a div, at a specific place (200, 100) but it always gets positioned in the top left corner (0, 0). What am I doing wrong?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Matching Game</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body id="theBody" onload="build_set()">
    <h1>Matching Game</h1>
    <div id="leftSide" style="position:absolute; top:100px; left:0; width:500px; height:500px"></div>
    <div id="rightside" style="position:absolute; top:100px; left:500px; width:500px; height:500px; border-left:3px solid black"></div> 
    <script>
        function build_set() {
            var leftSide = document.getElementById("leftSide");
            var rightSide = document.getElementById("rightSide");
            var smile = document.createElement("img");
            smile.setAttribute("src", "http://home.cse.ust.hk/~rossiter/mooc/matching_game/smile.png")
            smile.style.top = "200px";
            smile.style.left = "100px";
            leftSide.appendChild(smile);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image is not absolutely positioned, so the `left` and `top` will be ignored.

Add the following to your javascript:

```
smile.style.position = 'absolute';
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vnsucy24/1/) of the working version.

Answer (score 5):

You need to set `position` for img also. Here's [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2vna4304/)

```js
        function build_set() {
            var leftSide = document.getElementById("leftSide");
            var rightSide = document.getElementById("rightSide");
            var smile = document.createElement("img");
            smile.setAttribute("src", "http://home.cse.ust.hk/~rossiter/mooc/matching_game/smile.png")
            smile.style.top = "200px";
            smile.style.left = "100px";
            smile.style.position = "absolute";
            leftSide.appendChild(smile);
        }
        build_set();
```

```html
    <h1>Matching Game</h1>
    <div id="leftSide" style="position:absolute; top:100px; left:0; width:500px; height:500px"></div>
    <div id="rightside" style="position:absolute; top:100px; left:500px; width:500px; height:500px; border-left:3px solid black"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the speedy answer!